# Generic repository issue after migrating from .NET Framework 4.52 to .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am migrating legacy code from .NET Framework 4.52 to netstandard1.4 (FWIW, I am also migrating from EF 6 to EF Core).

MY problem stems from `IDbSet<T>` not being currently implemented in EF Core.

In EF 6, `IDbSet<Plugin>.Add(entity)` returns a proxy of the Plugin type.

In EF Core, `context.Set<Plugin>.Add(entity)` returns {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin]}.

I'm getting the following exceptions when casting from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin] to Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin in EF Core.

Q - How can I cast this?

## EF 6 RepositoryBase.cs

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T, U>
    where T : class
    where U : DbContext, new()
{
    private U _dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;
    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        object dao =  _dbset.Add(entity);
        return dao as T;
    }
```

}

## EF Core RepositoryBase.cs

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T>
    where T : class
{
    //private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;  // IDbSet is not implemented in .NET Core 1.0.1
    private readonly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<T> _dbset;
    private readonly CoreEFContext _context;
    protected RepositoryBase(CoreEFContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbset = _context.Set<T>();
    }
    public virtual T Add(T entity, out CustomMessage customMessage)
    {
        object dao = _dbset.Add(entity);
        return dao as T;
    }
}
```

The [repository](https://github.com/RandyDaddis/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/AspNetCoreMvcSampleCode.RefactoredGenericRepository/src/Dna.NetCore.Core.DAL.EFCore/Repositories/RepositoryBase.cs) is available in GitHub.

## At RepositoryBase.cs line 64:

### Locals Window:

> this._dbset.Results View = **"Enumeration yielded no results"**
>   this._context.ChangeTracker.Non-Public
>   members.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure.Instance.Entries[0]
>   = **does contain the entity**

### Immediate Window:

(Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin)dao

> '(Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin)dao' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
>      Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>      HResult: -2147467262
>      HelpLink: null
>      InnerException: null
>      Message: "Specified cast is not valid."
>      Source: null
>      StackTrace: null

dao as T

> 'dao as T' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>      Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>      HResult: -2147467261
>      HelpLink: null
>      InnerException: null
>      Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>      Source: null
>      StackTrace: null

dao.GetType()

> {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin]}
>
>      Assembly: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60}
>
>      AssemblyQualifiedName: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[[Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin, Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"
>      Attributes: Public | BeforeFieldInit
>      BaseType: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry}
>      ContainsGenericParameters: false
>      CustomAttributes: Count = 0
>      DeclaredConstructors: {System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo[1](https://github.com/RandyDaddis/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/AspNetCoreMvcSampleCode.RefactoredGenericRepository/src/Dna.NetCore.Core.DAL.EFCore/Repositories/RepositoryBase.cs)}
>      DeclaredEvents: {System.Reflection.EventInfo[0]}
>      DeclaredFields: {System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0]}
>      DeclaredMembers: {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[5]}
>      DeclaredMethods: {System.Reflection.MethodInfo[3]}
>      DeclaredNestedTypes: {System.Reflection.TypeInfo.d__23}
>      DeclaredProperties: {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[1](https://github.com/RandyDaddis/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/AspNetCoreMvcSampleCode.RefactoredGenericRepository/src/Dna.NetCore.Core.DAL.EFCore/Repositories/RepositoryBase.cs)}
>      DeclaringMethod: '((System.RuntimeType)(dao.GetType())).DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>      DeclaringType: null
>      FullName: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[[Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin, Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
>
>      GUID: {bbf992a5-ba4d-3ab3-8a66-fa5a37a909ae}
>
>      GenericParameterAttributes: '((System.RuntimeType)(dao.GetType())).GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>
>      GenericParameterPosition: '((System.RuntimeType)(dao.GetType())).GenericParameterPosition' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>
>      GenericTypeArguments: {System.Type[1]}
>
>      GenericTypeParameters: {System.Type[0]}
>
>      HasElementType: false
>
>      ImplementedInterfaces: {System.Type[1]}
>
>      IsAbstract: false
>
>      IsAnsiClass: true
>
>      IsArray: false
>
>      IsAutoClass: false
>
>      IsAutoLayout: true
>
>      IsByRef: false
>
>      IsCOMObject: false
>
>      IsClass: true
>
>      IsConstructedGenericType: true
>
>      IsEnum: false
>
>      IsExplicitLayout: false
>
>      IsGenericParameter: false
>
>      IsGenericType: true
>
>      IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
>
>      IsImport: false
>
>      IsInterface: false
>
>      IsLayoutSequential: false
>
>      IsMarshalByRef: false
>
>      IsNested: false
>
>      IsNestedAssembly: false
>
>      IsNestedFamANDAssem: false
>
>      IsNestedFamORAssem: false
>
>      IsNestedFamily: false
>
>      IsNestedPrivate: false
>
>      IsNestedPublic: false
>
>      IsNotPublic: false
>
>      IsPointer: false
>
>      IsPrimitive: false
>
>      IsPublic: true
>
>      IsSealed: false
>
>      IsSecurityCritical: true
>
>      IsSecuritySafeCritical: false
>
>      IsSecurityTransparent: false
>
>      IsSerializable: false
>
>      IsSpecialName: false
>
>      IsUnicodeClass: false
>
>      IsValueType: false
>
>      IsVisible: true
>
>      MemberType: TypeInfo
>
>      MetadataToken: 33554824
>
>      Module (System.Reflection.MemberInfo): {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll}
>
>      Module: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll}
>
>      Name: "EntityEntry`1"
>      Namespace: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking"
>      ReflectedType: null
>      StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
>      TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
>      TypeInitializer: null
>      UnderlyingSystemType: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin]}

## Plugin_UpdateHandler.cs line 56 returns:

> Dna.NetCore.Core.DAL.EFCore.Repositories.RepositoryBase.**Add returned null**  Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Plugins.Plugin

Comment: `EF 6 to EF Core` that's like the cause. You should reduce this code by 95%.

Comment: Stop targetting .NET Standard 1.5 and 1.6 please, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/

Comment: @lex Thanks for the link to a very informative article. I would like to point out the following excerpt for those who have not heard the news:
**"In order to allow .NET Framework 4.6.1 to support .NET Standard 2.0, we had to remove all the APIs from .NET Standard that were introduced in .NET Standard 1.5 and 1.6."**

Comment: @usr This ancient legacy code was my first attempt at an ASP.NET framework application. While it has worked it production, it is definately in need of refactoring. I welcome pull requests and/or [code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @usr The purpose of this question is to facilitate the completion of a Proof of Concept repository which migrates legacy .NET Framework code to .NET Core. The purpose of that migration is to: (1) gain a deeper understanding of.NET Core, (2) discover issues in migrating legacy code to .NET Core, (3) test migration of third-party libraries to a .NET Core environment, and (4) share knowledge with the open source community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the entity via the `Entity` property on DbSet. You could directly return the parameter or access the `EntityEntry<T>`object to give ER Core complete control over what to do:

```
public virtual T Add(T entity, out CustomMessage customMessage)
{
    var entry = _dbset.Add<T>(entity);
    ...
    return entry.Entity;
}
```

Be aware that currently EF Core does not have EF 6's proxy functionality.